# iterating over a temporary table and for each row update another tables row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a temporary table with two columns in it, shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (
    id VARCHAR(50),
    gid int NULL
)
```

My problem is that I need to iterate over each row in #Temp1 and update another table, something like below although I'm struggling how to do this in an sql script?  Can anyone provide this for me?

```
foreach(row in #Temp1)
{
  UPDATE MyTable SET Column1 = row.gid WHERE id = row.id
}
```

Many thanks,
James

Comment: Why is there an id with datatype varchar(50) if I may ask?

Comment: just when I wrote it quickly that is what I used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do a join between the tables something like this

```
UPDATE M 
SET M.Column1 = T.gid 
FROM #Temp1 T INNER JOIN MyTable M
ON T.id = M.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you need

```
Update MyTable 
Set column1 = (Select gid FROM #Temp1 t WHERE t.Id = MyTable.Id)
```

Comment: I get the following error Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. assuming the data is clean, you should be able to just cast the varchar ID into a guid or vice versa. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
If the varchars can't be converted into a guid, then there may be a data issue there.